# Set a max count

Tags: php, image

Is there any way to put a limit (say, 2) to this script so that it shows me 2 images at the time on the latest date modified?

This script shows me the images from a directory and puts them in a modified order, so the latest image comes first. Now, I want to set a maximum for this script.

```
# To prevent browser error output
header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');
# Path to image folder
$imagefolder = '*';
# Show only these file types in the image folder
$imagetypes = '{*.jpg,*.JPG,*.JPEG,*.png,*.PNG,*.gif,*.GIF}';
# Add images to array
$images = glob($imagefolder.$imagetypes, GLOB_BRACE);
# Sort the images based on its 'last modified' time stamp
$sortedImages = array();
$count = count($images);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $sortedImages[date ('YmdHis', filemtime($images[$i])).$i] = $images[$i];
}

# Set to 'false' if you want the oldest images to appear first
$newest_images_first = true;
# Sort images in array
if($newest_images_first) {
    krsort($sortedImages);
} else {
    ksort($sortedImages);
}
# Generate the HTML output
writeHtml('<ul class="ins-imgs">');
foreach ($sortedImages as $image) {
    # Get the name of the image, stripped from image folder path and file type extension
    $name = 'Image name: '.substr($image,strlen($imagefolder),strpos($image, '.')-strlen($imagefolder));
    # Get the 'last modified' time stamp, make it human readable
    $last_modified = '(last modified: '.date('F d Y H:i:s', filemtime($image)).')';
    # Begin adding
    writeHtml('<li class="ins-imgs-li">');
    writeHtml('<div class="ins-imgs-label">'.$name.' '.$last_modified.'</div>');
    writeHtml('<div class="ins-imgs-img"><a name="'.$image.'" href="#'.$image.'">');
    writeHtml('<img src="'.$image.'" alt="'. $name.'" title="'. $name.'">');
    writeHtml('</a></div>');
    writeHtml('</li>');
}
writeHtml('</ul>');
writeHtml('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ins-imgs.css">');
# Convert HTML to JS
function writeHtml($html) {
    echo "document.write('".$html."');\n";
}
```

Comment: Maybe `array_chunk` ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_slice](http://php.net/array_slice) to return up to the first 2 elements in the images array:

```
foreach (array_slice($sortedImages,0,2) as $image) {
    //your code
}
```